# How to keep my Pytrainer data after a fresh install of Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am thinking about doing a fresh install and setting up a dual boot Windows and Ubuntu system. I need to keep my data from [Pytrainer](https://github.com/pytrainer) on the new system. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Find the directory Pytrainer uses to save it's information at, and copy it all to another drive for safe keeping while you perform your format and reinstall of the dual OS.

I've never used the program but that's all I would do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what directory do you think it would be saved.Thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know enough about the filesystem yet, I would just poke around, but I'm not at my Ubuntu computer and I have never used that software.